# Get data from the function based on the type passed without using if-else or switch

Tags: javascript

I want to get the variables values based on the parameter passed to the function. Is there any way to do this:

```
 getDaysInCurrentMonth(type = 'all') {
      const date = new Date(),
            month = date.getMonth(),
            year = date.getFullYear(),
            days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
      if (type === 'all') return { date, month, year, days };
      return [type];
  }
```

For example, if I pass days in the `getDaysInCurrentMonth('days')`, it should only return days. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can access it like this: `getDaysInCurrentMonth().days`

Comment: you can use switch statement.

Comment: You could do something evil: `return eval(type)`

Comment: What is the problem of putting them in an object and get them by property name?

Comment: @VLAZ, yes we can do that and it can be done which is what I was thinking. But I wanted to know is it in any way possible to get the variables values using type param.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara then you are asking for [“Variable” variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530). Which is not possible (outside of `eval` which you shouldn't use and don't need to use). And the accepted answer there does show that it's much easier with an object.

Comment: Yes, I went through the thread and it make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a single parameter, you could create an object and then access it by key. For example

```
getDaysInCurrentMonth(type = 'all') {
  const date = new Date(),
        month = date.getMonth(),
        year = date.getFullYear(),
        days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  const result = { date, month, year, days };
  if (type === 'all') return result;
  else return result[type];
}
```

You would have to be sure to only call the method with the specified types or add error handling though.

Comment: Yes, definitely I can do that, but why to create another space and then use it.  cant we send the variables values directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
getDaysInCurrentMonth(type = 'all') {
  const date = new Date(),
        month = date.getMonth(),
        year = date.getFullYear(),
        days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  const result = { date, month, year, days };
  return (type === 'all') ? result : result[type]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, there is.

Your end function should look something like this:

```js
const getDaysInCurrentMonth = (type = 'all') => {
     const date = new Date(),
            month = date.getMonth(),
            year = date.getFullYear(),
            days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    switch(type){
        case "all": return { date, month, year, days };
        case "month": return { month };
        case "date": return { date };
        case "year": return { year };
        default: return `Unknown type ${type}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP question clearly states "*without using if-else or switch*"

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a dictionary and save your values in Key-Value pairs where key is the parameter you accept as an argument to the function.

```js
function getDaysInCurrentMonth(type = 'all') {
            const obj = {};
      const date = new Date;
      const month = date.getMonth();
      const year = date.getFullYear();
      
        obj["date"] = date;
      obj["month"] = month;
      obj["year"] = year;
      obj["days"] = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
      
      return obj[type] || date.toLocaleString();

  }
 
 console.log(getDaysInCurrentMonth("year"));
 console.log(getDaysInCurrentMonth("month"));
 console.log(getDaysInCurrentMonth("days"));
```

Comment: It does not look very DRY; if you have `const month = date.getMonth();` then you can do `obj["month"] = month;`, there is no point in doing `obj["month"] = date.getMonth();` and why should you generate a `new Date` to give a value to `obj["days"]`, when yu already have `date`?

Comment: @secan I have simply used the provided code by the OP. I wanted to provide a solution with minimum modifications so its easier to understand.